# MySQL - change many rows of dates

Tags: mysql

I have a fairly large number of rows where a datetime field is stored such as:

0010-01-03 00:00:00

But, I need it to be:

2010-01-03 00:00:00

Any suggestions on how to mass change rows from 0010 to 2010?

Comment: Are they stored in a DATE field, or just as formatted characters?

Comment: if it 1999 how you will store?

Comment: Days and Months of the rows are different.  Also, I only want to update the rows that have year set to 0010 and not touch the rows with year set to 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this :

```
UPDATE table SET date = date_add(date, INTERVAL 2000 YEAR) WHERE YEAR(date) < 11;
```

If you have years like '0099' :

```
UPDATE table SET date = date_add(date, INTERVAL 1900 YEAR) WHERE YEAR(date) > 10 AND YEAR(date) < 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table SET field = field + INTERVAL 2000 year;
```

Take a look on MySQL [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) . =]

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table
SET field = '2010-01-03 00:00:00'
WHERE field = '0010-01-03 00:00:00'
```

Without more information, this is the only real answer I can give.

Comment: Thanks for fast response.  Yes, of course I could run this update for the one row that matches.  But, there are many, many more with different months and days.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytimefield = mytimefield + INTERVAL '2000 years' where mytimefield < now() - INTERVAL '15 YEAR';
```

Not sure if that's the exact syntax for MySQL.  It might be

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytimefield = DATE_ADD(mytimefield, INTERVAL 2000 YEAR) mytimefield < DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 15 YEAR);
```

Comment: I'll give it shot later tonight.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `2000` into year.

Answer (score 0):

add 2000 years to values with a year lower than 2000, that should definitely fix it